# FILTER Function error

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a dataset in this format.

[image]

When I write the filter function, there is an error that the function is not valid.

```
=FILTER(A2:L26263,E2:E26263=A26266,"")
```

I trim the E column and change date format to General and Text but none of them work. Could you help me with this?

Comment: It works for me, do you have `FILTER`? it is only available with subscription to Office 365.  What error do you get?

Comment: @ScottCraner the error is "the function is not valid"

Comment: I have Microsoft office professional plus 2016

Comment: Do you use `;` instead of `,` as your delimiter?  Should the formula be: `=FILTER(A2:L26263;E2:E26263=A26266;"")`